# GET POST запросы. Полный контроль над полученными ответами

Tags: c#, .net, post, get, request

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть данный код отправляющий POST зарос и получающий ответ от сервера:

```
private readonly WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        public async Task<string> POST(string URI, string body, string AccessToken = null)
        {
            try
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                if (AccessToken != null)
                {
                    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", AccessToken);
                }
                string result = await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(URI, body);
                return result;
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                log.WriteLog("RaidBoss", we.ToString());
                return null;
            }

        }
```

При каждом ответе отличающимся от 200 срабатывает Exeptions С которого можно вытащить код ответа но не JSON код который был отправлен мне в ответ.

Каким образом можно обрабатывать все ответы (любой код без вызова исключения)? Возможно, нужно будет использовать другой способ отправки  POST.

И та же проблема с GET запросами:

```
public async Task<string> GET(string URI, string Params = "", string AccessToken = null)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
                if (AccessToken != null)
                {
                    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AccessToken);
                }
                Task<Stream> result = hc.GetStreamAsync(URI + "?" + Params);

                Stream vs = await result;
                StreamReader am = new StreamReader(vs);

                string res = await am.ReadToEndAsync();


                return res;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Подскажите куда копать в данном случае. Буду очень благодарен!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ииспользуйте GetAsync/PostAsync, который вернет HttpResponseMessage, который **не делает автоматически** EnsureSuccessStatusCode(), который и кидает исключение. А из HttpResponseMessage можно достать и хидеры и тело ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @vitidev за помощь в решении данного вопроса.

Результат вышел таким:

POST:

```
public async Task<string> POST(string URI, object body, string AccessToken = null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    if (AccessToken != null)
                    {
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AccessToken);                    
                    }

                    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8);
                    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URI, httpContent);
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLog("Action: POST", ex.Message, 101);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

GET:

```
        public async Task<string> GET(string URI, string Params = "", string AccessToken = null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    if (AccessToken != null)
                    {
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AccessToken);
                    }

                    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI + "?" + Params);
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.WriteLog("Action: GET", ex.Message, 102);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

POST и GET коды ответа можно получить внутри самой функции с помощью :

```
              if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){}           // Код 200
              if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound){}     // Код 404
              if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized){} // Код 401
              if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent){}    // Код 204
              if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict){}     // Код 409
```

И много-много различных кодов в `HttpStatusCode`

Answer (score 1):

При ответе отличном от 200 может и не быть никакого json. Вам нужно копать в сторону разделения ответственностей: отдельно операция обращения к сайту, отдельно операция парсинга json. Траспортный слой отдельно, декодирование сообщений отдельно.

В базовом классе - собственно выполнение запроса (кинули строку - получили строку):

```
public class WebServiceBase
{
    public string MakeRequest(string url, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            // ...
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

В api уже можно оперировать TRequest и TResponse:

```
public class WebsiteService : WebServiceBase
{
    public TResponse Call<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request)
    {
        this.Call<TRequest>(request);

        try
        {
            var answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(this.Response);
            return answer;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    private string Call<TRequest>(TRequest request)
    {
        this.Request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        this.Response = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            this.Response = this.MakeRequest(this.RequestUrl, this.Secret, this.Request);
            return this.Response;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    private string Request { get; set; }

    private string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: тело при ответе отличном от 200 будет всегда тк. я произвожу обмен данными со своей API. Да даже если и не всегда можно сделать проверку на размер Content'a. Но все равно спасибо за ваш ответ.